Open sqlite database in flutter project folder
I have a sqlite database located in the assets/database folder of my flutter project, and I want to open it using Moor package, but I can't find how. This is what I came up with after surfing the net, but it's still not working. Although, I've seen some solutions online, but those were made with sqflite package.
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:nursescbt/app/data/dtos/answers_dto.dart';
import 'package:nursescbt/app/data/dtos/questions_dto.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:moor_flutter/moor_flutter.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart'; 



class Answers extends Table {
  IntColumn get answer_id => integer().autoIncrement()();
  IntColumn get question_id => integer().autoIncrement()();
  TextColumn get answer_text => text()();
  BoolColumn get is_correct => boolean()();
}

class Questions extends Table {
  IntColumn get question_id => integer().autoIncrement()();
  TextColumn get question_text => text()();
  IntColumn get category_id => integer()();
}



@UseMoor(tables: [Questions, Answers])
class AppDatabase extends _$AppDatabase {

  AppDatabase()

      : super(_openConnection());

  @override

  int get schemaVersion => 1;

  //Future<List<Question>> getQuestions() => select(question).get();

}

LazyDatabase _openConnection() {

  return LazyDatabase(() async {

    final dbFolder = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    final file = File(path.join(dbFolder.path, 'cbt.db'));

    if (!await file.exists()) {

      final data = await rootBundle.load('assets/database/cbt.db');

      final bytes =

          data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);

      await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);

    }

    return VmDatabase(file);

  });

}

